# Angular 15 Upgrade Unit Tests Failing with ReferenceError: Window is not defined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have recently upgraded to angular 15, however I'm getting errors while running my unit tests. Below is what they are all failing on - "Window is not defined." Nothing except installed packages have been changed, so maybe I am completely missing something or there is a dependency that I need to update, but not sure why this is happening or what I need to do, to correct this problem.

```
    FAIL   user-management  libs/user-management/src/lib/user-management.module.spec.ts
      ● Test suite failed to run
    
        ReferenceError: Window is not defined
    
          20 |
          21 |   constructor(
        > 22 |     @Inject(WINDOW) private readonly window: Window,
             |                                              ^
          23 |     private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
          24 |     private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
          25 |     private readonly injector: Injector
    
          at Object.<anonymous> (../common-ui/src/lib/window/window-manager.service.ts:22:46)
          at Object.<anonymous> (../common-ui/src/index.ts:3:1)
          at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/user-management.module.ts:17:1)
          at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/user-management.module.spec.ts:2:1)
    
    Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
    Tests:       0 total
    Snapshots:   0 total
    Time:        2.07 s
```

This is the service where it fails in my tests, in the constructor where "WINDOW" gets injected:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, ComponentFactoryResolver, ApplicationRef, Injector, InjectionToken, ComponentRef, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { WINDOW } from './window.service';
import { DomPortalOutlet, ComponentPortal, ComponentType, PortalInjector } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ComponentWindowRef } from './component-window-ref';
import { CdkConnectedOverlay, Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { containerProvider, WINDOW_OVERLAY_CONTAINER } from './custom-overlay-container';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export const PORTAL_DATA = new InjectionToken<{}>('PortalData');
export const WINDOW_HOST_PROVIDERS = [
  containerProvider,
  Overlay,
  CdkConnectedOverlay
];

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WindowManagerService {
  
  readonly windows: any = {};

  constructor(
    @Inject(WINDOW) private readonly window: Window,
    private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
    private readonly injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.observeStyles();
  }
```

This is what my angular version looks like:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.10
Node: 18.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.10
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.13
@angular/cdk                    15.2.9
@angular/material               15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.10
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.9.5
webpack                         5.78.0
```

These are the packages in my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.10",
    "@azure/app-configuration": "^1.5.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.17.0",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-common": "^2.8.16",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js": "^2.8.16",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-properties-js": "^2.8.16",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.16",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.17",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^14.8.9",
    "@schematics/angular": "^15.2.10",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.14",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^14.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fontawesome-pro": "^5.14.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-filesaver": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.2.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.10",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "15.4.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "^15.9.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "^15.9.7",
    "@nrwl/jest": "^15.9.7",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^15.9.7",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "^15.9.7",
    "@politie/angular-testcafe-builder": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "gherkin-executor-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.8.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "lcov-result-merger": "^3.3.0",
    "openssl-self-signed-certificate": "^1.1.6",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "testcafe": "^2.6.2",
    "testcafe-reporter-xunit": "^2.2.3",
    "testcafe-tools": "^1.1.18",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.78.0"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": "./testResults",
    "outputName": "junit.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "true",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  }
```

I have tried adding in my package.json file, window like a global:

```
"globals": {
    "window": {}
 }
```

I have also tried downgrading my jest packages but nothing so far has made a difference. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `import { WINDOW } from './window.service';` it comes from your service... so did you provide it?

Comment: That import does exist in the window-manager.service file. Are you saying it also needs to be in the .spec files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide one. Typically using TestBed

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   providers:[{provide: WINDOW, useValue: yourWindowMockGoesHere}]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have applied the changes as you've suggested, but I am still getting the same results. Here is what I added to my spec file: 

      beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

          declarations: [ UserLeftNavComponent ],
          providers: [{
            provide: WINDOW, useValue: mockWindow
          }]
        })
        .compileComponents();  

      }));

Not sure if I am just implementing this incorrectly.